# HBase: how to get next row?

Tags: java, hbase

i'm trying do some filter in hbase. and i'm thinking about how to get the next row of specific row? like this, if the `rowkey = userid+timestamp`, and the records about one of user would be like `"{userA+timestamp1, ...}, {userA+timestamp2, ...}, ...`". And if I want to get the next row of `"userA+timestamp1"`, the return should be a row like "`userA+timestamp2, ...".`

the easy way to solve the probelm is `setStartRow(userA+timestamp1)`, and do some filter like `RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,new RegexStringComparator("userA")),` but it returns too many rows?

if I want to just return one row(exactly next row), how can I do this?

Comment: you could use `LIMIT>=1` to get only one row from hbase shell same is available in java Client API as well

Comment: I think you are looking for `PrefixFilter`